# UITableViewDataSource and Multithreading

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm running into index beyond bounds exception in one of my `UITableViews` and I *think* it could be down to some multithreading issues. Here's what I believe is happening:

1. I have a `UITableView` and it's data source is a regular `NSMutableArray`.
2. This `NSMutableArray` which is backing my `UITableView` is updated every couple of seconds with the contents of an API response.
3. After each update, `UITableView`'s reloadData is being invoked to ensure that the user sees new data from the API server.
4. Sometimes a index beyonds bounds exception gets thrown.

Here's my code:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) currentBetEvents
{
    return  currentMarketId == nil ? [[BFOpenBetsModel sharedInstance] betEvents] :     filteredBetEvents;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{    
    NSArray *betEvents = [self currentBetEvents];
    return [betEvents count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *betEvents = [self currentBetEvents];
    id obj = [betEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] // this is where it blows up
```

Basically, I get an exception while trying to access an object in the betEvents structure at index 0.

What I *believe* is happening is:

1. `reloadData` is called on the `UITableView`
2. `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is invoked which returns a value > 0.
3. a rouge thread arrives and clears out the `UITableView`'s data source.
4. `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is invoked and it bombs.

Is there any way to ensure that this doesn't happen? Do I need to start using some primitive locks on the data source to ensure that it doesn't get updated while the table is being updated?

---

**EDIT**
Took another look at how the data structures returned by currentBetEvents can be altered and it looks like the filteredBets & betEvents can be cleared out as a result of the following code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kUserLoggedOutNotification object:nil];
```

This notification is posted whenever the user logs out. Whenever a user logs out of the app, I need to clear out the filteredBets and betEvents arrays. Is it possible that the following could happen:

1. `reloadData` is called on the `UITableView`
2. `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is invoked which returns a value > 0.
3. User logs out which kicks off the notification & clears out the data structures.
4. `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is invoked and it bombs.

---

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: Are you implementing numberOfRowsInTableView?

Comment: I think you need to show how betEvents gets updated, and how you then inform the table view that it needs to be updated.

Comment: rdelmar - I'm not implementing numberOfRowsInTableView. Just numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSectionsInTableView. Edited my answer to include some more information on how the bet arrays are getting updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely sounds like a threading problem. You might try something like this:

```
// view controller
@synchronized([[BFOpenBetsModel sharedInstance] betEvents])
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

…

// data model
@synchronized(_betEvents) // or whatever the instance variable -betEvents returns is
{
    [_betEvents addObject:whatever];
}
```

Comment: Hi Noah. As the NSTableView drawing is happening on the main UI thread, could I just ensure that all edits to the bet events are executed on the main UI thread too?

Comment: That could work too, but in general you don’t want to do anything data-heavy on the main thread as it can hurt the responsiveness of your app.